# I want to create table from json in snowflake dynamically by parsing the json string that is in JSON_FILE column

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table in snowflake with name "gsc_json". it contains a column name "JSON_FILES" that contains jsons. I just want to parse that json to create a table with data dynamically. Want to create table for row where id=1. Please anyone can help then let me know. I have json code like below. we can set tablename as we want like abc.

{
"page_desktop_image": {
"responseAggregationType": "byPage",
"rows": [
{
"clicks": 0,
"ctr": 0,
"impressions": 1,
"keys": [
"https://francais.chip.ca/pret-hypothecaire-inverse-ressources/comparer-avec-chip/hypotheque-inversee-vs-home-equity-lignes-de-credit/"
],
"position": 111
}
]
}
}

Comment: Please add to your question the table structure and contents that you want to achieve, based on the json example you've provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of below articles , which might help you to have ideas to achieve what you are after;

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extracting-JSON-using-LATERAL-FLATTEN

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extract-multi-level-JSON-object-using-lateral-flatten

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/json-data-parsing-in-snowflake